# SQL query for rows migration to distinct occurences of their relations

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have following data structure containing sample data:

**Groups Table**

| id (PK) | name | foreign_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | DUPLICATED_NAME | X |
| B | DUPLICATED_NAME | X |
| C | string | Y |
| D | string | Z |

**Items Table** (related to **Groups**)

| id (PK) | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| uuid value1 | A |
| uuid value2 | B |
| uuid value3 | C |
| uuid value4 | D |

My goal is to get rid of *id* column in **Groups** and make *name* and *foreign_id* columns new composite primary key.

For this, I need to migrate existing **items** to distinct occurrences of **groups**.
In example I've posted it means, that I need to delete group which *id* = B because of *DUPLICATED_NAME* clashing with **group** **A**, and then reassign all **items** with *group_id* = **B** to **A**, since **B** no longer exists, and so on, for all rows.

I'm using PostgresSQL and Liquibase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=12f2d30b17448c7ffe08a04ee242179e)

```
UPDATE items i
SET group_id = s.first_value  -- 3
FROM (
    SELECT
        i.*,
        g.first_value
    FROM items i
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            *,
            -- 1
            first_value(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name, foreign_key ORDER BY id)
        FROM groups
    ) g ON g.id = i.group_id  -- 2
) s
WHERE i.id = s.id;
```

1. Use the [`first_value()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to find the first id value for the duplicates group, which is added as only value to all records of the group (= partition)
2. Join the `group` table on the `items` table by the old `group_id`
3. Update the `items` table using the `first_value`

---

If you want to execute the `DELETE` statement for the `groups` table in the same query, you can use [CTEs (`WITH` clauses)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for that:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=de1f1aac1e7696551efeee95295b0144)

```
WITH new_group_id AS (
    SELECT                                  -- 1
        i.*,
        g.id as g_id,
        g.first_value
    FROM items i
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            *,
            first_value(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name, foreign_key ORDER BY id)
        FROM groups
   ) g ON g.id = i.group_id
), update_items AS (
   UPDATE items i                           -- 2
   SET group_id = s.first_value
   FROM (SELECT * FROM new_group_id) s
   WHERE s.id = i.id
)
DELETE FROM groups                          -- 3
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT g_id
    FROM new_group_id
    WHERE g_id <> first_value
);
```

1. First calculate the new group_id as we did above. Store the result in a CTE because we reuse it later twice.
2. Do the `UPDATE` statement like we did above. Only difference is that we do not use a subquery but the previously calculated CTE result
3. After updating we can use the query once more to find the records which should be deleted (every record where the `first_value` is not the same as the actual group's `id`). Execute the `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Hello @S-Man, this looks really good, I appreciate your answer! I'll be testing the solution right away, so today I'll let you know about it (probably accept your answer because it's very detailed).

Comment: I have one comment to this solution - if there are no matching items to given group, such groups won't be deleted.